# Java Regular Expression - How to get the words between symbols

Tags: java, regex

I have the text line

> ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.ru

I must get **Ivan Ivanov** via RegEx

Answer (score 2):

Use `split(";")`.

Example:

```
String line = "ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.ru";
String name = line.split(";")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
(?<=;)([^;]*)(?=;)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rR1wP0/2)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `StringTokenizer` to achieve this task. Look at the example [here.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/)

Comment: Don't suggest legacy class. `StringTokenizer` should be replaced by `Scanner` or simple `split` call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is well formed you could solve it in multiple ways:

```
 String str = "ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.ru";
 System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf(";") + 1, str.lastIndexOf(";")));
 /*Regex*/
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*;(.*);.*");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
 if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
 }
 /*Using split*/
 String name = str.split(";")[1];
```